# How to .toggle an Image randomly without having to .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

I'm putting together a Loch Ness Monster website.
I have two images of Nessie that I've been trying to slide onto the screen from the left and right side at random intervals without having to be prompted by the user.
In details, the images are supposed to:

- slide on the screen from the left hand side, then slide off, and then
- slide on from the right hand side, then slide off.

both on random intervals.

I realize I need to probably be using the `.animate` function, `math.random`, and possibly `.toggle` but I'm very new to JavaScript and jQuery and have no idea how to piece the code together.

If anyone could help me I'd be extremely thankful !

```
$(function() {

});

function animateNessie() {
    var randomTime = // use Math.random to update randomTime var for its next use
        setTimeout(function() { // animate Nessie graphic (see jQuery.animate)
            $().animate({
                left: '50px'
            });
            //hide Nessie graphic
            //call function again
            animateNessie();
        }, randomTime);
}
```

*(Someone in my class tried to put together a loose outline, but they weren't really sure either.

I'd rather not use bootstrap because of having to go through the process of downloading it,

plus I'm not really good with it yet)*

Comment: show us the code of what you have so far

Comment: You can do that quickly with bootstrap components. Carousel is the one, it will make the magic, you can customize it, and its responsive for all or most devices and browsers. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

What you're thinking of is a carousel. It's easier to use Bootstrap for this, but I do know of a natural jQuery solution. I thought this might be helpful.

You'll want to use `setInterval` but pass in random values for this. Let's say for example, you wanted the intervals to randomly be between 1 and 10 seconds.

```
var randomTime = Math.floor(Math.random() * 9000) + 1000;
```

This will select a random number between 1000 and 10000, which will be passed into the second parameter of setInterval. This measures the number of miliseconds it will take for your code to run.

You then need to get your images. Assuming you only have two images, you would use this code.

```
var image1 = $("img:eq(0)");            // Selects your first image
var image2 = $("img:eq(1)");            // Selects your second image
```

Hide the second image with the `hide()` method.

```
image2.hide();
```

To run a function continuously, we use `setInterval`. Since we want to alternate, we just call the `toggle()` method which checks if an image is hidden or not.

```
setInterval(function() {
    $("img").toggle();
}, randomTime);
```

Here's a fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/sx3fnpuy/1/

Comment: woah that looks great. if i wanted the images to slide on and off the screen, could I replace .toggle with .animate?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how to do that, but my guess was using `fadeToggle`. With `animate`, it would be slightly more complicated. Here is the fiddle for the fadeToggle. It has a little more of an effect. http://jsfiddle.net/sx3fnpuy/2/

Comment: that's a cool effect! what i really need though is it to slide on the screen from the left hand side, then slide off. and then slide on from the right hand side, and then slide off, at random intervals. maybe i should just turn to bootstrap. :/

Comment: That would be a good idea. It turns out his is harder than I thought. That's one of the benefits of using a built-in-library like Bootstrap. You don't have to reinvent the wheel. Could save you a lot of headaches down the road